# How should I write a method for array of classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, rspec

I would like to be able to use method below to use it like this: `clear_tire_index_for Answer, Question`

```
  def clear_tire_index_for(resource)
    resource.index.delete
    resource.tire.create_elasticsearch_index
    resource.index.refresh
  end
```

How to do that?

Comment: resource should be an object or a class name ?

Comment: ``resource`` should be class name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def clear_tire_index_for(*resources)
    resources.each do |res|
        res.index.delete
        res.tire.create_elasticsearch_index
        res.index.refresh
    end
end

clear_tire_index_for Answer, Question
clear_tire_index_for Answer
```